# Is there a more elegant way of getting a value from a TypeScript enum, if it exists?

Tags: typescript, enums

If I have an Enum of allowable values, like:

```js
enum PackagingUnits {
  Be = 'becher',
  Bg = 'bogen',
  Bi = 'bidon'
}
```

I want a function to pass a string in to get an enum value, by key, so `getPackagingUnitName('Be')` would return `'becher'`.

The naïve version of this would be:

```js
function getPackagingUnitName(key: string): PackagingUnits | null {
  if (PackagingUnits[key]) {
    return PackagingUnits[key]
  }
  return null
}
```

However, TypeScript (version 3.3.3 atm) does not like this, and complains that `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.` for every instance of `PackagingUnits[key]`.

I have tried a few variations of the if-condition (like `Object.keys(PackagingUnits).includes(key)`, that makes the if-condition error-free, but this still gives the same error for the return statement, `return PackagingUnits[key]`.

`return PackagingUnits[key as PackagingUnits]` does not work either.

The only working syntax I have been able to come up with is:

```js
function getPackagingUnitName(key: string): PackagingUnits | null {
  const puIndex = Object.keys(PackagingUnits).indexOf(key)
  if (puIndex !== -1) {
    return Object.values(PackagingUnits)[puIndex]
  }
  return null
}
```

Is this really the best possible way to do this?

N.B.: Yes, this could be done easier if `PackagingUnits` was not an enum, but it needs to be so for other uses.

Comment: what do you want to get? the 'becher' part? or the 'Be' part?

Comment: @distante you'll find the answer to that question right after the enum code block ;)

Comment: Jeez I am blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't treat access of an unknown property as a way of doing control flow narrowing to assert the existence of that property.  You can only access properties on an object type if the compiler knows there is (or might be, in the case of optional properties) a property at that key.  So as soon as you do `PackagingUnits[key]` where `key` is an arbitrary `string`, the compiler complains that `PackagingUnits` doesn't have a `string` index.

The *easiest* way to fix this is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and move on:

```
function getPackagingUnitName(key: string): PackagingUnits | null {      
  if ((PackagingUnits as any)[key]) { // assert your way out
    return PackagingUnits[key as keyof typeof PackagingUnits]; // assert your way out
  }
  return null;
}
```

This works but isn't guaranteed to be type safe by the compiler.  You might not care, since the issue is inside an implementation of a function that other developers aren't going to mess with.  If so, then great.

---

If you want the compiler to guarantee that what you are doing is type safe, you need to lead it through the analysis by careful steps.  First you'd like the compiler to treat the `PackagingUnits` object not as something with three known keys whose values are `PackagingUnits` types, but instead, treat it as something which has a value at *every* string key, whose value is `PackagingUnits | undefined`.  (This is as close as you can get to [optional index signatures](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7118) since TypeScript doesn't always [distinguish missing properties from `undefined`-values properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195)).  So you'd like this:

```
const PackagingUnitsIndexSignature: {[k: string]: PackagingUnits | undefined} =
  PackagingUnits; // error!
```

This should be safe (the type `typeof PackagingUnits` is a strict [subtype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) of `typeof PackagingUnitsIndexSignature`) but the compiler doesn't realize it.  The `enum` nature of `PackagingUnits` seems to confuse it.  So we can do a two-step widening... first to a plain object type whose keys and values match that of the enum:

```
const PackagingUnitsPlainObject: Record<keyof typeof PackagingUnits, PackagingUnits> =
  PackagingUnits; // okay!
const PackagingUnitsIndexSignature: { [k: string]: PackagingUnits | undefined } =
  PackagingUnitsPlainObject; // okay!
```

Now we finally have something we can index into with a `string` without error:

```
function getPackagingUnitName(key: string): PackagingUnits | null {
  if (PackagingUnitsIndexSignature[key]) { // okay!
    return PackagingUnitsIndexSignature[key];  // error!!!!
  } else {
    return null;
  }       
}
```

Ugh, what happened?  Shouldn't control flow narrowing work since we just checked the presence of a property at `key`?  Unfortunately, [bracket-type indexed access doesn't always narrow values the way we'd like](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  Rather than force this to work, let's just take it as a given that `PackagingUnitsIndexSignature[key]` returns `PackagingUnits | undefined`.  If so, we should be able to use the [logical "or" (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) to replace `undefined` with `null`:

```
function getPackagingUnitName(key: string): PackagingUnits | null {
  return PackagingUnitsIndexSignature[key] || null;  // okay
}
```

And the compiler is happy.  To put all that together, here is a roundabout way to write the same logic so that the compiler confirms that it is type safe:

```
const PackagingUnitsPlainObject: Record<keyof typeof PackagingUnits, PackagingUnits> =
  PackagingUnits; // okay!
const PackagingUnitsIndexSignature: { [k: string]: PackagingUnits | undefined } =
  PackagingUnitsPlainObject; // okay!
function getPackagingUnitName(key: string): PackagingUnits | null {
  return PackagingUnitsIndexSignature[key] || null;  // okay!
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Cool workaround for getting the union into a `{ [k: string]: PackagingUnits | undefined }`

Comment: Heroic effort to get around the limitations of TypeScript's parser. I know it cannot understand every possible JavaScript syntax, but I can't imagine a scenario where `Object.keys(PackagingUnits).includes(key)` check would not make `PackagingUnits[key]` safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
function getPackagingUnitName(key: keyof typeof PackagingUnits): PackagingUnits | null {
    if (PackagingUnits[key]) {
        return PackagingUnits[key];
    }
    return null
}
```

Of course, it is just in case, the `key` is got from an API or something like that. Otherwise the function is not really necessary. If you want a type check to ensure the key is one of the predefined values, just use

```
key: keyof typeof PackagingUnits;
```

Comment: if your parameter is already typed as key: keyof typeof PackagingUnits there is no need for if statement since you can not pass any string as parameter...

Comment: yes, true. I just wonder if key is something defined from the app or get from an API, if it is the second case, the check is still needed, because the type check will not be helpful anymore

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but it's not a "type check" and it doesn't ensure anything, it's a type *assertion*, which is you promising the compiler that this will be the case ;)